# How do you add integer elements from an array and output using JOptionPane?

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

Heres what i have. The user enters number of appointments for 7 days, but Im confused on how im suppose to add the integers the user inputed from the arrays? any advice on how I can go about doing this?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AdvisingAppointmentTracker {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Step 1: Set any constants needed for the program
  final int NUM_DAYS = 7;
  final int MIN_NUM_APPOINTMENTS = 0;

  // Step 2: Create an array that will hold the number of advising appointments per day
  int appointments[] = new int[NUM_DAYS];

  // Step 3: Enter the number of advising appointments for all of the days      
  for(int i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++)
     appointments[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of appointments"));
  // Step 4: Find the average number of appointments


  // Step 5: Output the average number of appointments

  }   
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add/use the numbers in the array? Use the same for loop in your code again.

Comment: how so? i've tried using int total +=appointments; but i get error saying its not a statement

Comment: You need to include the array brackets to access the numbers you stored. `total += appointments[i]` would work. You could also do `for(int n : appointments) total += n;`

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach

```
int numberOfAppointments = 0;
for(int appointment : appointments){
    numberOfAppointments += appointment;
}        
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numberOfAppointments / appointments.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step tutorial.

First, create a variable that stores the total sum of the array elements.

```
int sum = 0;
```

Then, it's the hard part!

You see how you can loop through an array with this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++)
```

And access the an element in the array using this?

```
appointments[i]
```

That is exactly what you should do! You should combine those two together!

```
for(int i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++)
    sum += appointments[i];
```

If you don't quite get it, here is the English translation of the code

> for each of the items in the array appointments
>
> add the item to sum

So `appointments[i]` here basically means "each item in appointments".

You can also rewrite the loop in a more elegant way:

```
for (int appointment : appointments)
    sum += apppointment;
```

As you can see here, if you use this kind of loop, you don't need to write `appointments[i]` anymore. You replace that with `appointment`.

Now you can just calculate the average very easily:

```
int average = sum / (double)appointments.length;
```

"Wait a minute! Why `(double)`?" you asked. Actually, that isn't necessary. You only need this if you want to get a result with decimal places, because an `int` divided by an `int` is always an `int`!